# Auto count Microsoft Planner Bucket by using Power Automate

Tags: automation, power-automate, bucket, microsoft-planner

I'm trying to use Power Automate to automate tasks, The task is to auto count Planner buckets for Not started, In progress, Late, Completed, basically is like shown below, instead of "Tasks left", I want to count it as "Buckets left".
I tried to create a flow in Power Automate but fail in the compose step, which using length() to check how many buckets

[image]

[image]

Below is list bucket json code:

```
"body": {
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.plannerBucket)",
    "@odata.count": 1,
    "value": [
        {
            "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzEtQnVja2V0QEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBARCc=\"",
            "name": "Bucket 2",
            "planId": "k1BcbVn74EO5PxjqUddPdskAHsKA",
            "orderHint": "85852759",
            "id": "XArIHyfZK0O8ezDOUmiKzskAOgIM"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is Compose part, using length() to count the number of buckets

```
length(body('List_Buckets'))
```

Comment: Seems like this question is missing the question.

Comment: Show us the JSON that you’re working with.

Comment: Hi Skin, thank you for your suggestion, I had added the JSON code and the length() code that I'm using